# Active Admin resource index: showing filtered collection count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activeadmin

I'm basically trying to show the count of the filtered collection in the resource index page title when a filter is run -- ie 'Users - 3' when someone checks to see how many Users signed up today -- much like it's doing in the pagination on the bottom of the page -- but I can't seem to figure out how to display it as part of index :title =>  x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to prepend the resource name, you simply need to perform the concat'ing in the proc:

```
index :title => proc{ "Users - #{collection.count}" }
```

Haven't tested it out, but that should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `index :title => collection.count` or `index :title => proc {collection.count}` or @users instead of collection

Comment: I had tried collection.count and resource.count - but the proc is what did it; thanks!

Comment: Ok curious - what if I wanted to pretend with the class ie "Users - 56"

Comment: index :title => "Users - #{ proc {collection.count} }" ? - not sure

Comment: Nope that didn't work; it'll print out #<Proc...>.  Nor will index :title => "Users - #{ (proc {collection.count}).call}", as that will give me undefined local variable or method `collection' for #<ActiveAdmin::ResourceDSL:0x007ff621a5ee88>   -- Nor will index title: proc {|collection| "Users - #{collection.count}"}